# Why does ALTER TABLE report no records on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to investigate the cause of a slow query in MySQL; I posted about the query itself previously:[How to investigate and optimise a slow MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452168/how-to-investigate-and-optimise-a-slow-mysql-query)

However, I'm asking this question separately because it potentially relates to a different problem that may underlie the first, and I'd be grateful for your insights, please.

I sent the problem referred to above to a colleague who runs a major University's website that is also based on Drupal, which I'm using. He executed the query on their server using a snapshot of our database and, compared with the tens of seconds it took my system, they were getting results in fractions of a second. For the record, our server is well-powered; we're not running a site on a Raspberry Pi or something!

He then did an explain on the query on his server and found that their set up is handling the query quite differently to ours.

[image]
This led him to question the integrity of the index in my table, because:

On his server:

> mysql> alter table taxonomy_term_data ENGINE=InnoDB; Query OK, 11589
>   rows affected (0.26 sec) Records: 11589  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

On ours:

> mysql> alter table taxonomy_term_data ENGINE=InnoDB; Query OK, 0 rows
>   affected (0.40 sec) Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

The above was entered to see if we could regenerate the index, on the off-chance that it is corrupt.

I've since tried dumping the table and then re-importing it, as per his suggestion, but that has not made any difference.

I must admit that I am completely out of my depth, and my colleague is unsure why the ALTER table operation, on our production server, is returning 0 records compared with the correct 11,000+ he sees on their test server, despite importing a dump of our db.

Any advice that anyone can offer me to investigate this would be truly helpful.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you both using the exact same version of MySQL?

Another reason why the execution plan might differ is if statistics are outdated; cost-based optimizers rely on stats to choose execution plan. I've seen cases (in Oracle however) where performance would improve/degrade just because stats were re-collected.

Comment: I must admit that I don't know and this is something I have written back to ask. However, the difference in the execution time is so gross (orders of magnitude) for the query that something must be wrong with my config...

Comment: Have you tried to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE taxonomy_term_data;` on your table and see if it changes anything (should re-analyze everything and rebuild index s it might take time)?

Comment: Yes - I did that and nothing changed. It was very fast though - could that be a bad sign? The table is quite simple though - just a list of node ids and the accompanying associated taxonomy terms.

Comment: By looking at the `EXPLAIN` statement in the image, it seems the query that is running in the code on your server is different than that on your colleague's server. `<derived2>` is missing in your code. `echo` the query or compare the files on both the servers.

Comment: I think that's a temporary table; why my server is not generating it though, I don't know.

The query that produced that explain result is the same one listed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452168/how-to-investigate-and-optimise-a-slow-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment84690809_48452168

Comment: Please make your question self-contained, including a [mcve]. Eg neither this question nor the link contain DDL, which is critical. Eg we don't really know what code you ran.

Comment: You'll get "0 rows affected" if the engine does not change (just run it again and he will get 0 rows too). So you ran the test on different engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem and here is the (very simple) solution, just in case anyone else is struggling with it.

I also gratefully acknowledge the help of Andy Batey at Cambridge University who spotted the issue and helped me.

The clue was that they are running MySQL 5.5; we are on 5.7. On 5.5 the query is fast; on 5.7 it's dreadfully slow.

This led to this thread: [query extremely slow after migration to mysql 5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733946/query-extremely-slow-after-migration-to-mysql-5-7)

For me, the same query executed on the two different platforms was taking a fraction of a second (v5.5) vs 12s (v5.7).

Adding:

```
"optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'"
```

...to my.cnf resulted in the same query now taking 0.05s on v5.7.

I hope this helps anyone else who runs into this upgrade issue. I had spent days trawling fora and groups asking for help and also trawling through the query itself to try to optimise it....